# Problem Adding Attachment Using Variables with Outlook.MailItem

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I can't send email with attachments, *if the path of the attachment isn't hard-coded into the vba, itself*.

I get "error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method" at this line:

```
.Attachments.Add Me.LinkedFile1
```

On my form is a simple textbox called LinkedFile1.

Right now, Me.LinkedFile1 = "C:\Users\pat.lewis\Desktop\description.docx"

It works just fine when I send an email from Outlook using this code:

```
With olMail
    .To = Me.EmailTo
    .CC = Me.EmailCC
    .Subject = Me.EmailSubject
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .Body = Me.EmailMessage
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\pat.lewis\Desktop\description.docx"
    .Send
End With
```

But it doesn't work if I assign the value of Me.LinkedFile1 to the .Attachments.Add property:

```
With olMail
    .To = Me.EmailTo
    .CC = Me.EmailCC
    .Subject = Me.EmailSubject
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .Body = Me.EmailMessage
    .Attachments.Add Me.LinkedFile1 'DOESN'T WORK!!
    .Send
End With
```

It Also does not work if I assign the value of Me.LinkedFile1 to a string variable then reference that:

```
Dim olAttachment1 As String

If IsNull(Me.AttachedFile1) = False Then
    olAttachment1 = Me.LinkedFile1
End If

With olMail
    .To = Me.EmailTo
    .CC = Me.EmailCC
    .Subject = Me.EmailSubject
    .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
    .Body = Me.EmailMessage
    .Attachments.Add olAttachment1 'DOESN'T WORK EITHER!!
    .Send
End With
```

I have confirmed multiple ways that the value of Me.LinkedFile1 does actually equal
"C:\Users\pat.lewis\Desktop\description.docx".

Any ideas on what I could be missing here?

Comment: LinkedFile1 is a textbox bound to a text field? Method works for me.

Comment: It's an unbound textbox, but its value is set to a string pathname at the time the email tries to send.  Should have included this: I get "error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method" at this line:  ` .Attachments.Add Me.LinkedFile1 `

Comment: You should edit your question with that info. You already know using a static string works so setting the olAttachment1 string variable to a static string should work as well (you might test just to confirm). So, there is something wrong with unbound textbox. How is this textbox value set? Could try a global variable or TempVar instead of textbox.

Comment: I edited the question.  When I assign a static string to a variable and use the variable, it works fine. The textbox value is set by Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker). But I'm convinced the textbox and its value are as expected. I've tested it a dozen ways (assigned value of textbox to pc clipboard, used a messagebox to display value on run, etc). And when the run fails on error, I can hover over the control name in the module and I can see the full pathname to the file. So I don't know. It's just weird.

Comment: I can only suggest next to test setting string variable directly with FilePicker result. Can still set textbox if you want to display to user.

Comment: Fantastic! When I set the variable with the FilePicker result value, it worked. Good thinking. So grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UNBOUND textbox set with result of FilePicker works just fine for me.

Only issue with textbox I can think of that would cause this failure is corruption. If running Decompile/Compile and/or Compact & Repair and/or deleting & replacing textbox does not resolve, eliminate it from the process. Set olAttachment1 variable directly with result of FilePicker. You can still set the textbox if you want to display to user.

Comment: You're right. I did a decompile and then recompiled and the problem vanished using the unbound textbox. Thank you so much for weighing in.